# Get multistage dockerfile from image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I have tried `docker history` and `dfimage` for getting the dockerfile from a docker image.

From what I can see, any information about the multistage dockerfiles is not there.  As I think about it, it makes sense.  The final docker image just knows that files were copied in.  It probably does not keep a reference to the layer that was used to construct it.

But I thought I would ask just to be sure.  (It would be really helpful)

For example: I have a multistage docker file that, in the first stage builds a dot.net core application, then in the second stage copies the files from that build into an Nginx container.

**Is there any way, given the final image, to get the dockerfile used to do the build?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this wont be possible since your final docker image won't contain anything from the "builder" stage. Basically the builder stage is a completely different image which was built, the files were copied from it during the build of the final image and than it was discarded.

The stages from the builder stage will live on in your build cache and you could even tag them to run some kind of docker image analyzer against them. However this does not help you, if you only have access to the final image...

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Docker image will only have its own history and not the multi stages that may have been used before it